# Dynamically increasing observation space for a gym environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to build a dynamic gym environment for a snake game. As the score increases, naturally, the snake's length increases. To simulate dynamicity, I'm adding obstacles (walls) to the game gradually as the score increases (when the score is a multiple of 5). All the coordinates of a wall are stored in a list and every time the score passes a multiple of 5, a new segment is added at a random position and this is appended to the list.

While referring to existing solutions, I noticed that there are two ways of mentioning the observation space:

- The first one includes passing the entire window (this hasn't worked too well for me) using gym.spaces.Box.
- The second one is a more compact representation which resulted in a better score. The observation space included variables like the snake's coordinates, the food's coordinates, and the window size using gym.spaces.Dict.

I would like to implement the second approach for my environment, but I don't have any idea how I would pass the walls' coordinates.

P.S.: This is my first time asking a question on stack-overflow so if there's any issue/ mistake in my way of asking, do let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would suppose the wall coordinates are similar to the snake or food coordinates.

Comment: Hello Bhupen, sorry for replying late. But, I ended up using a similar approach as to the one suggested by yours. I made an array of wall coordinates